# Can anyone recognise the location and uniforms in these pictures

Tags: germany, identify-this

I came across these photos which I believe to be a European city.
I was wondering if the knowledgable travellers of this group can name the city and who is in the uniforms (Police, Army)

I appears to be some form of occasion like a remembrance or similar. I've managed to narrow down the country to Germany given the badge on the shoulder in the second picture.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivU8hCihd1L9fjPS52lOBxuhJyJd4kD-pZrS9BVWLZrNH-eCcnCrv4LSOL4V8-B2CM8zBFMXMHQBI6YhnDpRfsyiZZsmysw2genJjwcJ7QI6CkSUus-xmriBKxX8Spvkqn979OXHiHs3UkfJYwmtYraasM0G1jl8hL4FsktEfv-q-5eAFEcPk1I6uqiLxe6sJEWuCrKB0YfrSz0q_1VFCYsvvz0ir7BaYPAgSSjFUTcnfLC1s3SUSSW29cklKW4cvn0deqxSwAR3MVmFQBE-Jlt5vLru2w7wV9QRMzrMcEVNHipdCAsEuXxUr29IfbP9ujvbUAOn) works wonders for questions like this.

Comment: @JanDoggen: I clicked on your link, and I got pictures of Pontococ High School Marching Band, Navy SEALs, Haredi ultra-Orthodox Jews, Soldiers of the Romanian army, etc. etc. How is this supposed to help?

Comment: @TonyK Yes, Google search results can differ per person.  'My' results lead to the answer. [Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed) already took the trouble of writing [a good answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/144324/40521) And this is supposed to help because I gave the OP a method to find these kinds of things. I did not have the time for a proper answer, so I gave him a net instead of a fish.

Comment: @JanDoggen: So what results did _you_ get from Google image search? Presumably the same random dross that I got. So why do you claim that it works wonders? I'm baffled.

Comment: @TonyK: Google search results differ between people. Google attempts to learn from your past searches and give you more relevant results. For instance, if you search for "jaguar", are you interested in the car, or in the big cat? If you recently also searched for "tiger", "lion" and "cheetah", then cat hits will be sorted to the top in your search for "jaguar". Thus, it's quite possible for your search results to differ from JanDoggen's. See [filter bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble).

Comment: @StephanKolassa: This is Google image search we're talking about, not Google search. Imperfect as it is, I think it can tell the difference between a cat and a car.

Comment: @TonyK: I'm not saying it can't figure out the difference between a cat and a car. I am saying that when you search for "jaguar", Google tries to understand whether you are more likely to be interested in the cat or in the car. Based on your past search (and other) history. And this just as an example for why different people will get different results *for the same search*. Not ["the same random dross that I got"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144323/can-anyone-recognise-the-location-and-uniforms-in-these-pictures?noredirect=1#comment358627_144323).

Comment: @StephanKolassa: I think this is just a misunderstanding we have here. By "Google image search", Jan Doggen meant that you give it an image file and Google tries to find the image. This doesn't work very well. But you meant that you give Google a keyword and it shows you some related pictures; which is a very different thing. I agree with what you say, now that I understand what you mean!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is called a [Großer Zapfenstreich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fer_Zapfenstreich), the people on the second picture are Joachim Gauck and Ursula von der Leyen, at the time when Gauck was president and von der Leyen defense minister. It can take place on different occasions but the most common is to honor the president, now at [Schloss Bellevue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellevue_Palace_(Germany)) in Berlin. The second and third pictures were taken when Gauck left office in 2017 while the first one comes from another Großer Zapfenstreich, in Dresden.

Comment: this is not in Berlin, based on the 3 Church towers in the background of the first photo.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yeah, you're right, it doesn't look so typical of the Berlin skyline.  Yet, [this Spiegel article](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/joachim-gauck-bundespraesident-mit-grossen-zapfenstreich-verabschiedet-a-1139379.html) confirms that the second picture at least was taken when Gauck left office and it did happen in Berlin. Rotes Rathaus and the churches on the Gendarmenmarkt maybe? Although there are many modern buildings (Postdamer Platz, Fernsehturm) that I would expect to see in this general direction.

Comment: Note that I assumed this one was in Berlin too but upon reading my answer, I realise that I didn't actually write that. It's also possible that the pictures come from different events...

Comment: [The third one](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/grosser-zapfenstreich-zum-abschied-von-bundespraesident-joachim-gauck-14930145.html) is also definitely from Berlin. But still nothing on the first one. I edited the answer slightly based on this.

Comment: The first one is from Dresden. Different zoom/angle: https://live.staticflickr.com/5752/22438120367_56f9f8a511_b.jpg Found with the help of Google image search.

Comment: @Janka Thanks, I edited the answer based on this!